# Why offset duplicates in Confluent.Kafka at Consumer

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, confluent-kafka-dotnet

I'm using Apache Kafka as a Message Processor and using Confluent.Kafka in Asp.Net Core as a consumer.
I have to use a couple of consumers to process all the messages from the topic. My code works perfectly when I don't have any exceptions. 2 consumers work perfectly in parallel. The problem appears if I have an exception during message processing. Sometimes (not so often actually) I have Offsets duplication, which leads to the re-processing of already processed messages.

Here is the code, which emulates random exception throwing during processing.
One more time, if I delete random exception and launch 2 consumers, everything works perfectly. But with exception I have offsets duplicates...

```
class Program
{
    private const string Topic = "some-topic";

    private static void Main()
    {
        var config = new ConsumerConfig
        {
            BootstrapServers = "host list here",
            GroupId = "some-group",
            EnableAutoCommit = false,
            AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest
        };

        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                using IConsumer<Ignore, string> consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, string>(config).Build();

                consumer.Subscribe(Topic);

                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        const int batchSize = 5;

                        var readOnlyCollection = consumer.ConsumeBatch(batchSize);

                        bool error = new Random().Next(100) > 70;

                        foreach (ConsumeResult<Ignore, string> consumeResult in readOnlyCollection)
                        {
                            if (error)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine($"Stop at Offset: {consumeResult.Offset.Value}");
                                throw new Exception("Something happened");
                            }

                            Console.WriteLine($"Offset: {consumeResult.Offset.Value}");
                        }

                        Thread.Sleep(500);

                        consumer.Commit();

                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Inner exception: {ex.Message}");
                        consumer.Close();
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Outer exception: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is extension for batch processing:

```
static class ConsumerExtensions
{
    public static IReadOnlyCollection<ConsumeResult<TKey, TValue>> ConsumeBatch<TKey, TValue>(
        this IConsumer<TKey, TValue> consumer, int maxBatchSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        var message = consumer.Consume(cancellationToken);

        if (message?.Message is null)
            return Array.Empty<ConsumeResult<TKey, TValue>>();

        var messageBatch = new List<ConsumeResult<TKey, TValue>> { message };

        while (messageBatch.Count < maxBatchSize)
        {
            message = consumer.Consume(TimeSpan.Zero);
            if (message?.Message is null)
                break;

            messageBatch.Add(message);
        }

        return messageBatch;
    }
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: At-least-once delivery should be expected at all times, IMO. You will need to track record keys and/or processed offsets using some external system unless the dotnet consumer supports read-isolation from a transactional producer

Comment: @OneCricketeer so, you think that I have to deal with duplicates at consumer side?

Comment: Unless you want to commit before calling the consume method, causing at most once delivery (it'll skip offsets after a rebalance), that's correct.